# my HTML file cant load another file using load function(jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this example on w3schools.com and it should be working(it works on the website) but it doesn't work when I write it on my IDE(Atom).the home page is looking good but when I clicking the button nothing happened and it's not loading the demo_test.txt file. what am I doing wrong? or maybe something is missing?

home.html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

```
demo_test.txt
```

### jQuery and AJAX is FUN!!!

This is some text in a paragraph.

Comment: Something in the console?

Comment: Try to put `<script>` tag right before `</body>` .

Comment: @Aaron3219 I don't know. I don't have any alerts on the console. but the browser doesn't load the second file

Comment: @AhmedTagAmer I tried. still doesn't work

Comment: Is the file demo_test.txt on the same folder level as home.html?

Comment: @DaniloKörber yes

Comment: When I run this in Chrome I get  a CORS (cross-origin-requests) error.
You say you're not getting anything in the console at all? what browser are you on?

Comment: @Jonny I'm using chrome too

Comment: Are you using any localhost applications?

Comment: @AhmedTagAmer no

Comment: This is why it's not working, you must host your project or website on your localhost. i`ll post an answer now to describe this.

Answer (score 1):

To start use **Ajax**, you must host your website or application on your machine, this called **localhost**.

There is many FREE applications you can use to create a localhost:

- https://www.appserv.org/en/ .
- https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html .
- IIS *.

Download any of applications above and install it, it's very easy.

After installation, you can access your website with link `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` .

You can create localhost without using any applications with IIS (Internet Information Services), but it's complicated compared to above applications.

Comment: If this answer solved you problem, please accept it as correct answer.